# Bootstrap form looks funny

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have my [website's homepage here](http://siwiaza.org). When I click the login button, everything looks just fine. It's aligned correctly and everything. But when I literally copy and paste the exact same code to my password-changing page, the text fields go all screwy and get disaligned from their respective icons.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this alignment funkiness? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, by the way, if you couldn't tell.

Screenshots of pages and their respective source codes [can be found here](http://ge.tt/96RJeMk?c).

Comment: Please post related codes .

Comment: provide html of password-changing page

Comment: pls provide the css and js of corrosponding page

Answer (score 0):

I think your css files are interfering with eachother or you have them in a wrong order.
When I test the HTML by removing the CSS and inserting Bootstrap CSS ref it works.